# Adding values from objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects:

```
var array = [{
    id: "cards",
    amount: 5
}, {
    id: "shirts",
    amount: 3
}, {
    id: "cards",
    amount: 2
}, {
    id: "shirts",
    amount: 3
}]
```

What I need to do is loop through this array and find the total of all id types. 
So in this example, I would find the total amount of cards and shirts.

I'm not sure how to do this with objects. I've tried stripping the objects down with `Object.values(array)`, but is there a way to do it with the objects?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```js
var array = [
  { id: "cards", amount: 5 }, 
  { id: "shirts", amount: 3 },
  { id: "cards", amount: 2 }, 
  { id: "shirts", amount: 3 }
];

var result = array.reduce(function(entities, item) {
       entities[item.id] = (entities[item.id] || 0) + item.amount;
       return entities;
}, {})


console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You would loop your array, check the `id` property for your target object, then enumerate and outer scope variable with the value stored in the `amount` property.

```
var totalShirts = 0;
var totalCards = 0;
for(var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++){
    var entry = array[i];
    if(entry.id === "cards"){
        totalCards += entry.amount;
    }
    else if(entry.id === "shirts"){
        totalShirts += entry.amount;
    }
}
console.log("Total Cards: " + totalCards);
console.log("Total Shirts: " + totalShirts);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that gets the total of each item

```js
var array = [{id:"cards", amount: 5}, {id:"shirts", amount: 3}, {id:"cards", amount: 2}, {id:"shirts", amount: 3}];

var result = array.reduce(function(accumulator, current) {
  if (!(current.id in accumulator)) {
    accumulator[current.id] = current.amount;
  } else {
    accumulator[current.id] += current.amount;
  }
  
  return accumulator;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `forEach` will do the trick:

```
var counts = {}
array.forEach(v => {
  counts[v.id] = (counts[v.id] || 0) + v.amount
})
console.log(counts)
```

will print:

```
{
    cards: 7
    shirts: 6
}
```

Comment: Is `return` statement necessary?

Comment: @guest271314 -  I assume so because the return will add the new count to the counts object...?

Comment: @HappyGreybush `return` statement can be omitted. `counts[v.id] = (counts[v.id] || 0) + v.amount` assigns the value.

Comment: Indeed, return is not necessary, I had a solution using .map that I changed for a forEach and forgot about that :)
Edited

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and sum the amount.

```js
var array = [{ id: "cards", amount: 5 }, { id: "shirts", amount: 3 }, { id: "cards", amount: 2 }, { id: "shirts", amount: 3 }],
    result = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a.id] = (r[a.id] || 0) + a.amount;
        return r;
    }, {});
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I'm afraid that he wants total amount of each types, not just total amount of everything.

Comment: @Kinduser, i was thinking i was missing something.

Comment: @Kinduser i am so delighted ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a O(n) time solution.

```
var totals = new Object();

for(var i = 0;i < array.length;i ++) {
  var id = array[i].id;
  var amount = array[i].amount;
  if(totals[id] == undefined) {
    totals[id] = amount; 
  } else {
    totals[id] += amount;
  }
}
console.log(totals);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for..of` loop

```js
var array = [{
  id: "cards",
  amount: 5
}, {
  id: "shirts",
  amount: 3
}, {
  id: "cards",
  amount: 2
}, {
  id: "shirts",
  amount: 3
}]

let res = {};

for (let {id,amount} of array) {
  if (!res.hasOwnProperty(id)) res[id] = 0;
  res[id] += amount;
}

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a for-loop to do this:

```
var totalCards = 0; 
var totalShirt = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].id === "cards") {
        totalCards += arr[i].amount;
    } else {
        totalShirt += arr[i].amount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the magic in for loop. This example should be general enough:

```js
var array = [ {id:"cards", amount: 5}, {id:"shirts", amount: 3}, {id:"cards", amount: 2}, {id:"shirts", amount: 3} ];
var output = [];
    
for(var i of array) {
  if(!output[i.id]) {
    output[i.id] = 0;
  }
  output[i.id] += i.amount;
}
    
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [{id:"cards", amount: 5}, {id:"shirts", amount: 3}, {id:"cards", amount: 2}, {id:"shirts", amount: 3}];

var arr = [];
array.forEach(v => arr.push(v.id));
var newArr = [...new Set(arr)];
var arr2 = [];

newArr.forEach(function(v) {
  var obj = {};
  obj.id = v;
  obj.counter = 0;
  arr2.push(obj);
});

arr2.forEach(v => array.forEach(c => c.id == v.id ? v.counter += c.amount : v));
console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.forEach()` to iterate over each element of the array. The total object is an associative array where the index is the `id` field of array element objects.

```
var array = [{ id: "cards", amount: 5 },
             { id: "shirts", amount: 3 },
             { id: "cards", amount: 2},
             { id: "shirts", amount: 3 }];
var total = {};
array.forEach(function (el) {
  if (total[el.id]) {
    total[el.id] += el.amount
  } else {
    total[el.id] = el.amount
  }
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(total));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code

```
if (!Object.keys) {
    Object.keys = function (obj) {
        var keys = [],
            k;
        for (k in obj) {
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, k)) {
                keys.push(k);
            }
        }
        return keys;
    };
}
```

then you can do this in older browsers as well:

```
var len = Object.keys(obj).length;
```